# Monitor windows clients network connectivity

Tags: windows, monitoring, remote-desktop, wifi

I support a family members small business in my free time.  They have 8 laptops running Windows 10.  Their actual work gets done on a Windows Server 2016 Remote Desktop Server (running in Amazon AWS).

Recently, a few users have been complaining about disconnects/etc (or inability to connect).  I am 99% sure it is the wireless in their building.  I never have connectivity issues (when I try to connect wherever in the world that I am based on them saying they are having problems), and I have multiple monitoring services that are pinging the server every minute to make sure it is up and running (and alerts me when it is down).

They aren't really tech savvy, so I can't have them troubleshoot/diagnose connectivity issues.

I need some way of

1) having the clients "phone home" every 5 seconds or something to some server that tracks how they are connected (wireless/ethernet) and their signal strength (maybe?) and provide server side reporting that would let me see when they "drop off" the internet or

2) some utility that I can make them start when they are having problems that they can clearly read to me what is going on.

3) something along those lines that provides me an audit of what is happening.

I am stuck between a rock and a hard place.  I don't think it's the server disconnecting them, but I also can't currently reliably monitor their connections 24/7 to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You could simply put a batch on their desktop that tells them if they are on- or offline:

```
@ping <GATEWAY IP> -n 1 > NUL && echo YOU ARE ONLINE || echo YOU ARE OFFLINE
```

or do the same with their internet connection and your RDS:

```
@ping <GATEWAY IP> -n 1 > NUL && echo YOUR WIFI IS THERE || echo NOT THERE YOUR WIFI IS
@ping <RDS-IP> -n 1 > NUL && echo THE SERVER ONLINE IT IS || echo THE SERVER OFFLINE IT IS
```

2) Yes, there is one, it's called "Windows 10". It tells you exactly and very simple if you are connected to something or not, what kind of WiFi-Signal you are getting - and if you have WiFi, if there is an internet connection. Just have them watched the 'network connection' symbol.